# Reduce the background noise when recording in android

Tags: android, filter, android-ndk, noise-reduction

I have developed a app which record the sound & play at same time approximate 100ms delay by using audio track &  audio record class in android. But the played audio have lot of background noise. So there is any way in android to reduce the background  noise while playing.

Please don't tell me used to Audacity Software for reduce the noise because i am not saving the recorded audio. I am just save it in a buffer & play this buffer by audio track.Cab be implemented a filter to reduce the background noise  in android using NDK.

Comment: That may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916779/how-can-i-remove-background-noise-with-java-while-recording-audio-in-a-crowd-zo

Comment: ref to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087672/appropriate-audio-capture-and-noise-reduction/30931178#30931178

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing to do is play the audio back using the voice setting.  It will filter out most of the "hum" noise. AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL.  You can use the NoiseSupression filter if available. NoiseSuppressor.create(device.getAudioSessionId());

Answer (score -4):

You can use [ClearRecord](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ittiam.clearrecord) application. It is free. You can play audio with noise reduction on. While playing audio, the background noise gets eliminated and clear one can hear clear sound.

Comment: He want implement this in his app