# how to remove noise from buffer

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am integrating an media player kind of app

I have converted the audio file format into buffer, and I have applied bass,treble filters with high gain then i got noise.How to minimise or eliminate that noise from audio in ffmpeg  or is there any another way such that i can remove noise using java code by doing changes in byte i.e(audio buffer)

here is my code:

```
    void playSound(byte[] buf, final int size) 
 {     
     trackStereo.write(buf, 0,size);
     trackStereo.play();

    buf = null;
 }
bufSizeStereo =  AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    trackStereo = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufSizeStereo,
AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    bytes = new byte[bufSizeStereo];
```

how remove noise from byte before playing the audio

Thanks

Comment: Not a trivial problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319652/suppressing-noise-in-wav-files ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916779/how-can-i-remove-background-noise-with-java-while-recording-audio-in-a-crowd-zo

Comment: Please provide me some code..any logic that operates on byte buffer..So that noise will be removed.

Comment: Which of the techniques mentioned in those links do you think would be most usefully applied to your noise?

Comment: None of them are useful for me

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm not sure how anyone will be able to help you if none of those techniques are applicable to your problem...